# android activity how to clear top with same class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 4 activity   A1 A2 B C ，  A1 and A2  is the same Activity

```
A1 -> A2 -> B -> C
```

later. I want startActivity from C to  A1 ，

I used

```
it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

but it open the A2 ， not A1.

Comment: you want to open activity a1 from c but it is opening activity a2..Is that your question?

Comment: please post the code you have tried to startActivity from C to A1

Comment: @Arvindsinc2  yes

Comment: Have you tried setting A1 activity's property  android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

This is code to launch activity a1 from c. Place this inside class c from where you want to launch activity a1.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, a1.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

and inside android app manifest, place this within  tag. Replace 'myacticvity' with whatever class name you have given for class c:

```
<activity android:name=".myactivity">
```